# Using a .NET7 project how to pass in ContainerEnvironmentVariable parameter via command line for the donet publish command?

Tags: c#, .net, docker-container, .net-7.0, dotnet-publish

With .NET7 we can use the dotnet publish command to build a docker container. How do you pass in environment variables via the command line?

You can use the following to build the container and specify a container image name but how to specify the ContainerEnvironmentVariable: `dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 -p:ContainerImageName=MyContainer -c Release`

-p:ContainerEnvironmentVariable=? -> How to build this parameter?

since ContainerEnvironmentVariable is a more complex parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container